# jquery change even not working on IE

Tags: php, jquery

i have a department table in my db. and using a select box when i click a certain department i am getting the departments id and sending it to another query to get sub departments through jquery ajax. but my change function works only first time i refresh the page

```
<div id="depSearch">
<select name="DeptSearchBox" id="DeptSearchBox">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `unitname` FROM `units` ORDER BY unitname ASC";
$result = $database->query($sql) or die('cannot connect to the database');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo'<option value= "'.$row['unitname'].'">'.$row['unitname'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select> 
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#DeptSearchBox').change(function (e) {
        var formdata = $('#DeptSearchBox').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "../../includes/jqueryRequireFiles/display_phone_table.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                formdata: formdata
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#tele_table').html('<center><img src="../images/Sit_related/loader.gif" /></center>')
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn('1500', function () {
                    $('#tele_table').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is #pressed' here ? Can you give the html tag for this Id

Comment: Also, you have used `e.preventDefault();` but the `event` is not declared in the function()!!

Answer (score 0):

Replce pressed with DeptSearchBox in javascript part. I edit it.
Also you can delete e.preventDefault();

Comment: i have edited but still when i change option. change event seems not triggering...

Comment: add an alert('Test') into function body of your code. May be problem was in other part of your code